# Use bindings from .vimrc in IPtyhon vi-mode

Tags: vim, ipython, vi

I have been searching and can't find if there is a way to use my custom bindings from my .vimrc file in IPython in a simple, straightforward manner.

I'm looking if not for the solution to this, to some good advice from the experienced users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, IPython doesn't use Vim so the answer is no.

Comment: @romainl You seem to know a lot more than me about vi/Vim. Got some advice for a begginer? What would be a "seamless" aproach to this? I use everything I can in vi mode, and now I'm a lot with IPython.

Comment: I may know a lot more than you about vi/Vim but I don't use vi/Vim emulation anywhere. As for what you can do with IPython's "vi mode", see https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ or `$ man readline`, depending on how you installed it. "Vim everywhere" is a phase. You will eventually get over it.